# Show div for 15 seconds then show another div

Tags: javascript, delay, setinterval

I have a gaming website and I want to put a advertisement before the game. So can someone tell me how to show the advertisement div for 15 seconds which says below it. "The game will start in [time left] seconds". Then one the time is up then it will show the div which holds the game. In javascript please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/myDTK/1

```
var secondsLeft = 15;
var delay = 1000; // 1 second

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  if (secondsLeft > 0) {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'The game will start in ' + secondsLeft + ' seconds...';
    secondsLeft -= 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'block';
  }
}, delay);​
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a looking at [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). It allows you do something after a certain time. If you need more help let us know.

EDIT: I'm sorry I misread your question. A more appropriate method you should use is [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) so every second during the 15 seconds, you can show the time. Speransky's answer has the right idea.

Comment: or setInterval to do something every second

Answer (score 1):

```
    function doSome() {
       //do some
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
       doSome();
    }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the setTimeout function

eg.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //code to hide the div and how game div
}, 15000);
```

Comment: and what about the countdown timer?

Comment: @Alnitak same principle though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/uNaRH/) using jQuery.

Basically just make a function that adds the div, call that function whenever you need to, and then in that function do `setTimeout(removeFunction, 15000)` to call the remove function 15 secs later.

In order to do the countdown timer, you can call a function updateTimer once per second (again, `setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000)`) and have that function simply search for the timer and decrement the counter.